# Customizing SecureSocial module with play framework

Tags: playframework, securesocial

This is a beginner question with regard to using the SecureSocial(version 0.2.3 module with play framework (1.2.4)

- Is it possible to have custom routes?  When I use the `module::secure` in my routes file, I am being redirected to `localhost:9000/auth/login`.
  I would like to just use `localhost:9000/login`, `localhost:9000/logout` and so on
- Is it possible to custom style the login page for the different social providers?  I would like to have custom look and feel and also custom messages.

Comment: here's an article on SecureSocial, it might be of your interest http://playlatam.wordpress.com/2012/02/20/secure-json-services-with-play-scala-and-securesocial-by-matt-raible/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can mount the routes to / instead of /auth

```
 *     /                       module:securesocial
```

You can also define your own routes for the securesocial contollers, remove the module:securesocial line and copy the securesocial routes file contents into your own routes file with different mount points.

For the login page it can be customized by copying it from the securesocial module source (app/views) to app/views/securesocial/SecureSocial/ folder in your own project

Do not forget to check for changes when you switch to a new securesocial version.

Comment: Ok thanks, Somatik.  I will try it out this evening at home and mark your answer if it works.

Comment: Thanks that worked on both counts.  It is interesting to note that folder structure is case sensitive. Maybe it is because I am using linux.  To override, I had to create my custom login.html in the exact case that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

There is routes file for this module too. You can try to edit this one and configure your app